# How to easily concatenate nested lists without losing the attributes?

Tags: r, list, concatenation

I need a base solution to concatenate two lists into a specific nested structure while preserving the attributes.

Using `c()` gives me the wanted structure, but the attributes are gone.

```
Map(c, L1, L2)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 3 4
```

Using `list()` saves the attributes, but I want the structure one level less deeply nested.

```
Map(list, L1, L2)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [[1]][[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [[1]][[2]][[1]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [[2]][[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [[2]][[2]][[1]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
```

Finally following code gives me what I want

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  r <- c(L1[[i]], L2[[i]])
  r[[1]] <- `attributes<-`(r[[1]], attributes(L1[[i]]))
  r[[2]] <- `attributes<-`(r[[2]], attributes(L2[[i]]))
  r
})
```

Is there perhaps a less awkward base R way to do this?

#### Wanted output

```
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 3 4
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 3 4
# attr(,"foo")
# [1] 42
```

#### Data

```
L1 <- list(`attr<-`(list(1:2), "foo", 42), `attr<-`(list(1:2), "foo", 42))
L2 <- list(`attr<-`(list(3:4), "foo", 42), `attr<-`(list(3:4), "foo", 42))
```